# Codeigniter - Form_validation return values

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem with validation error in Codeigniter.

When call a form with a anchor when dsiplay data i havn't error but when call a form whit a form_open i have a error on all fileds.

Example view works:

```
<a href="contr/create" class="small-box-footer">
   ADD <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</a>
```

Example view NOT works:

```
<div>
    <?php echo form_open('contr/create', 'role="form" class="form-horizontal"  ');?>
         <button class="btn">ADD</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My controller

```
public function create() 
{   
    $data = array(
        // Set title page
        'title' => 'Aggiungi',
        'page_content'=> 'fly/v_insert'
    );

$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');    

$this->form_validation->set_rules('data', 'Data', 'required');


if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)     
{       
        $this->load->view('backend/layout/v_main', $data);
}
else
{
        $data = array(
            'datadb' => $this->input->post('data'),
        );
        $this->model->model_create($data);
        redirect('fly/index');

}

}
```

the viwe v_insert

```
    <?php   echo form_open_multipart('user/edit', 'role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="basic-validate" ');?>

    <h3 class="panel-title">
    <?php $data = array(
        'name'          => 'data',
        'value'         => set_value['data'],
        'class'         => 'form-control rounded',
        'type'          => 'text',
        );
        echo form_input($data) ?></h3>
    <?php echo form_error('data'); ?>
</form>
```

When show the viel in the 1 case I havn't error but when show the 2 case I have been mistaken.

Where is the problem ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have no input field with name="data" https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-form

Comment: yes, i have a filed with name data in the form. the view that you see is a external link.

Comment: Where is `data input` field?

Comment: May be try with ajax?

Comment: in the view named v_insert.  'page_content'=> 'fly/v_insert'

Comment: the viwe v_insert

    <?php  echo form_open_multipart('user/edit', 'role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="basic-validate" ');?>
    
    <h3 class="panel-title">
    <?php $data = array(
        'name'          => 'data',
     'value'         => set_value['data'],
        'class'   => 'form-control rounded',
     'type'   => 'text',
     );
        echo form_input($data) ?></h3>
    <?php echo form_error('data'); ?>
</form>

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to consider two things:

1. You haven't taken button type submit.
2. You haven't taken input name with data

It should be like this:

```
<div>
<?php 
 echo form_open('contr/create', 'role="form" class="form-horizontal"  ');
echo form_input('data', set_value('data'));
$data = array(
    'type'  => 'text',
    'name'  => 'data'
);
echo form_input($data);
?>

     <button type="submit" class="btn">ADD</button>
</form>
```

**Note:** I am considering you have loaded form_helper.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: i insert the v_insert view that call from 2 link above

Comment: Can you show me the error you are getting? Also use debugger to debug where exactly you are facing issue.

Comment: the error is <?php echo form_error('data'); ?> true.